# reverting with tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I view the Subversion log in TortoiseSVN

[image]

When I select a revision and right-click, I see the following options (among others):

- Update item to revision
- Revert to this revision
- Revert changes from this revision

Can someone explain what are the differences between these 3?

What I actually want to do is **temporarily revert my working copy** back to the selected version of the repository. Which of these options should I choose?

Comment: What is "temporary revert"? for which business task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should choose the second option.

Here's what you get when you click on the Help button in this dialog:

> **Update item to revision**
>
> Update your working copy to the selected
> revision. Useful if you want to have your working copy reflect a time
> in the past, or if there have been further commits to the repository
> and you want to update your working copy one step at a time. It is
> best to update a whole directory in your working copy, not just one
> file, otherwise your working copy could be inconsistent.
>
> If you want to undo an earlier change permanently, use Revert to this
> revision instead.
>
> **Revert to this revision**
>
> Revert to an earlier revision. If you have
> made several changes, and then decide that you really want to go back
> to how things were in revision N, this is the command you need. The
> changes are undone in your working copy so this operation does not
> affect the repository until you commit the changes. Note that this
> will undo all changes made after the selected revision, replacing the
> file/folder with the earlier version.
>
> If your working copy is in an unmodified state, after you perform this
> action your working copy will show as modified. If you already have
> local changes, this command will merge the undo changes into your
> working copy.
>
> What is happening internally is that Subversion performs a reverse
> merge of all the changes made after the selected revision, undoing the
> effect of those previous commits.
>
> If after performing this action you decide that you want to undo the
> undo and get your working copy back to its previous unmodified state,
> you should use TortoiseSVN → Revert from within Windows Explorer,
> which will discard the local modifications made by this reverse merge
> action.
>
> If you simply want to see what a file or folder looked like at an
> earlier revision, use Update to revision or Save revision as...
> instead.
>
> **Revert changes from this revision**
>
> Undo changes from which were made in
> the selected revision. The changes are undone in your working copy so
> this operation does not affect the repository at all! Note that this
> will undo the changes made in that revision only; it does not replace
> your working copy with the entire file at the earlier revision. This
> is very useful for undoing an earlier change when other unrelated
> changes have been made since.
>
> If your working copy is in an unmodified state, after you perform this
> action your working copy will show as modified. If you already have
> local changes, this command will merge the undo changes into your
> working copy.
>
> What is happening internally is that Subversion performs a reverse
> merge of that one revision, undoing its effect from a previous commit.
>
> You can undo the undo as described above in Revert to this revision.

Comment: Don asked what the **differences** are between the three. Your post only describe what the 3 options are, but it's very difficult to tell what the actual differences are (especially for those who are not well versed in English). All I understood from your post, is that by the end of the day, you'll end up with the same working copy regardless of which option you chose. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214939/update-item-to-revision-vs-revert-to-revision Peter Parker explains what the actual **difference** is between _update to revision_ and _revert to this revision_