# TortoiseSVN revert vs update

Tags: tortoisesvn

What's the difference between following?

1. (right click on the project folder) update to revision XXX
2. (right click on the log list) revert to this revision
3. (right click on the log list) revert changes from this revision

Answer (score 8):

1. (right click on the project folder) update to revision XXX

> Your project folder is updated to the revision XXX. After that update, your working copy is not at the latest revision anymore and you can not commit any changes you make. If you want to commit, you have to update your working copy again to HEAD. Which means you can't use this option to undo changes you've already committed but only to get a good look at an earlier time of your working copy. So: use this only to look, not to work.

1. (right click on the log list) revert to this revision

> All changes made up to the right-clicked revision are reverted (undo all from HEAD to rev). The changes are only done in your working copy, which you then can commit if you like.

1. (right click on the log list) revert changes from this revision

> Only the right-clicked revision is reverted. The revisions after the right-clicked one up to HEAD are **not** reverted. Use this if you only want to undo one single commit, not all commits since a specific revision. Again, since this is a revert: the changes are only done in your working copy, which you then can commit if you like.

Comment: how does `update to` and `revert to/from` treat local changes ( uncommitted changes ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

1) (right click on the project folder) update to revision XXX
Updates working copy to the latest repository revision while keeping your local modifications.

2) (right click on the log list) revert to this revision
[Update Item to Revision vs Revert to Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214939/update-item-to-revision-vs-revert-to-revision)

3) (right click on the log list) revert changes from this revision
The changes made in that revision and in that revision only are removed from the working copy while keep your local modifications.