# How to revert to old revision and then get back to HEAD revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to using TortoiseSVN (have used TortoiseHG before) and I'm having some problems going back and forth between different revisions.

So for example if I'm working on my project and I notice a bug. I then want to see if this bug was also there 1 week ago. I right click on my project map and choose  TortoiseSVN->Show log. Then I find a reviosn from a week ago and right click and select Revert to this revision. So far all good. I then see that the bug was indeed still there, I just hadn't noticed it, so now I want to go back to the HEAD revision. This is where I start to get problems. First of all when I open the Show log the bold text indicates that I'm still in the HEAD revision. If I right click on the project map and choose SVN Update it just says that I already have the HEAD revision and nothing happens. I then try to open the log, right click on the last revision and select Revert to this revision. This doesn't work either. At this point I'm frustrated nothing works, deletes my folder and does a SVN Checkout from the HEAD revision and then i can continue working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did: "revert to this revision", which tells SVN to undo all the changes since that revision, so that you can commit the changes to HEAD, making HEAD match that revision. This adds changes to your HEAD working copy so you can modify the repository.

What you wanted: "update to this revision", which tells SVN to make your working copy point to that revision, so that you can examine it, and then update back to the HEAD later. This moves your working copy to a different revision, so you can examine old repository states.

Comment: Ok, so if I just want to go back and look I use "update to this revision" and if I actaully want to "rollback" to that revision I use "revert to this revision" ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you roll back with "revert" you will also need to commit the changes however.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all when I open the Show log the bold text indicates that I'm
>   still in the HEAD revision. If I right click on the project map and
>   choose SVN Update it just says that I already have the HEAD revision
>   and nothing happens.

True, because by clicking `Revert to this revision`, you did `reverse merge` from HEAD to older revision. Your working copy is **still pointing to HEAD**, but has some local modifications.

If you want to go back to HEAD, just click:

`TortoiseSVN > Revert...`.

Go through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214939/update-item-to-revision-vs-revert-to-revision) to get much more details about this.