# Revert back to older version in TortoiseSVN and Commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN tool for the version management of my project. Till now, I have committed for 17 times. Now, I want to go back to 10th revision and start to make changes to the project and commit.

I have tried to do so by getting the 10th revision of the project and make changes. And then, I tried to commit. This says, "You are not having the latest version to commit" and it asks me to update the project to the head revision.

Is that possible to remove the last 7 commits and make the 10th revision as the head revision? 
Or
Is that possible to get the 10th revision and make changes and then commit to SVN?

Comment: I guess you did "Update to revision" which will not permit you to commit as SVN will tell you that your working copy is out of date and that you have to update first. What you have to do is "Revert to this revision" which will remove (in your working copy) all the revisions after the selected one. Go through this SO thread for a bit more detailes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1214939/1023562

Comment: You have not made quite clear what you want to achieve: do you want to discard all the work you have done between revisions 10 and 17? Or do you want to create a new branch of your project, perhaps for maintenance to a release based on revision 10 independent of the work towards the next release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the log dialog on your working copy root. Then right-click on revision 10 and select `Revert to this revision`.

All changes done from revision 10 to revision 17 are reverted. You can now commit that "undo" and then do the changes you want.

Comment: you can always merge those back again.